# How to display text on the center of an image, where there are 2 rows of images, with 4 images in each row

Tags: html, css

I want to have text on each image (center) and images should be next to each other, no spaces in between. There are 4 images in each row and 2 rows, so 8 texts. Each text that I want to display on an image is within div blocks (e.g Subnautica Image has text: Subnautica).

```css
.GameImage {
  width: 25%;
  height: 180px;
  float: left;
}

.GameImage:hover {
  filter: blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="Gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="SubnauticaImage" ">
            <img src="Slike/Subnautica.jpg " class="GameImage " alt="Subnautica Slika ">
            <h4 class="ImageText ">Subnautica</h4>
     </div>
        <div id="TheForestImage ">
            <img src="Slike/TheForest.jpg " class="GameImage " alt="The Forest Slika ">
            <h4 class="ImageText ">The Forest</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="OriAndTheBlindForestImage ">
            <img src="Slike/OriAndTheBlindForest.jpeg " class="GameImage " alt="Ori and the Blind Forest Slika ">
            <h4 class="ImageText ">Ori and the Blind Forest</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="CitiesSkylinesImage ">
            <img src="Slike/CitiesSkylines.jpg " class="GameImage " alt="Cities Skylines Slika ">
            <h4 class="ImageText ">Cities Skylines</h4>
        </div>        
    </div> 

    <div class="row ">
        <div id="RustImage ">
            <img src="Slike/Rust.jpeg " class="GameImage " alt="Rust Slika ">
            <h4 clas="ImageText ">Rust</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="KerbalSpaceProgramImage ">
            <img src="Slike/KerbalSpaceProgram.jpg " class="GameImage " alt="Kerbal Space Program Slika ">
            <h4 class="ImageText ">Kerbal Space Program</h4>
        </div>
        <div  id="HearthStoneImage ">
            <img src="Slike/HearthStone.jpg " class="GameImage " alt="HearthStone Slika ">
            <h4 class="ImageText ">Hearthstone</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="AngryBirds2Image ">
            <img src="Slike/AngryBirds2.jpg " class="GameImage " alt="Angry Birds 2 Slika ">
            <h4 class="ImageText ">Angry Birds 2</h4>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic code to center text on image

The main thing is that you have to make the `position` of image parent `relative` and the `position` of text `absolute`.

Then use `top` and `left` property to along with `transform` to center it

For more information on CSS positions refer [CSS Positions](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /*for example purpose*/
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-container .ImageText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="SubnauticaImage" class="img-container">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="GameImage" alt="Subnautica Slika" />
  <h4 class="ImageText">Subnautica</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) on you container, like this :

```css
#AngryBirds2Image {
     position: relative; /* Must set parent position relative in order to keep h4 inside of it */
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
#AngryBirds2Image h4 {
     position: absolute; /* to put it hover the image */
}
```